# Правильная реализация mp3 плеера

Tags: android, service

Как правильно реализовать воспроизведение музыки в mp3 плеер? имеется ввиду где воспроизводить в программе или в сервисе, или сначала в программе а при закрытии создавать сервис. Вообщем как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вот ссылка на open source проекты https://github.com/pcqpcq/open-source-android-apps. В разделе Multi-Media ты сможешь найти похожий на твой проект.